# Unique Object From Nested Object Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

**My current object is as follows**

```
{
    "payload": [{
        "id": "idval1",
        "type": [{
            "lists": [{
                "id": "1234",
                "value": "One",
                "ddid": "dd1",
                "name": "first value"
            },
            {
                "id": "1235",
                "value": "Two",
                "ddid": "dd2",
                "name": "second value"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "idval2",
        "type": [{
            "lists": [{
                "id": "1234",
                "value": "One",
                "ddid": "dd1",
                "name": "first value"
            },
            {
                "id": "1235",
                "value": "Two",
                "ddid": "dd2",
                "name": "second value"
            },
            {
                "id": "1236",
                "value": "Three",
                "ddid": "dd3",
                "name": "third value"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "idval3",
        "type": [{
            "lists": [{
                "id": "1234",
                "value": "One",
                "ddid": "dd1",
                "name": "first value"
            },
            {
                "id": "1235",
                "value": "Two",
                "ddid": "dd2",
                "name": "second value"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "idval4",
        "type": [{
            "lists": [{
                "id": "1234",
                "value": "One",
                "ddid": "dd1",
                "name": "first value"
            },
            {
                "id": "1235",
                "value": "Two",
                "ddid": "dd2",
                "name": "second value"
            },
            {
                "id": "1236",
                "value": "Three",
                "ddid": "dd3",
                "name": "third value"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "idval5",
        "type": [{
            "lists": [{
                "id": "1234",
                "value": "One",
                "ddid": "dd1",
                "name": "first value"
            },
            {
                "id": "1235",
                "value": "Two",
                "ddid": "dd2",
                "name": "second value"
            },
            {
                "id": "1236",
                "value": "Three",
                "ddid": "dd3",
                "name": "third value"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "idval6",
        "type": [{
            "lists": [{
                "id": "1234",
                "value": "One",
                "ddid": "dd1",
                "name": "first value"
            },
            {
                "id": "1235",
                "value": "Two",
                "ddid": "dd2",
                "name": "second value"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "idval7",
        "type": [{
            "lists": [{
                "id": "1234",
                "value": "One",
                "ddid": "dd1",
                "name": "first value"
            },
            {
                "id": "1235",
                "value": "Two",
                "ddid": "dd2",
                "name": "second value"
            },
            {
                "id": "1236",
                "value": "Three",
                "ddid": "dd3",
                "name": "third value"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

**Below is the object set I am expecting from current object**

```
{
    "payload": [{
        "id": "idval1,idval3,idval6",
        "type": [{
            "lists": [{
                "id": "1234",
                "value": "One",
                "ddid": "dd1",
                "name": "first value"
            },
            {
                "id": "1235",
                "value": "Two",
                "ddid": "dd2",
                "name": "second value"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "idval2,idval4,idval5,idval7",
        "type": [{
            "lists": [{
                "id": "1234",
                "value": "One",
                "ddid": "dd1",
                "name": "first value"
            },
            {
                "id": "1235",
                "value": "Two",
                "ddid": "dd2",
                "name": "second value"
            },
            {
                "id": "1236",
                "value": "Three",
                "ddid": "dd3",
                "name": "third value"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this using underscore or JavaScript.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You should describe what is unique about the second dataset. Right now, I have to almost guess to understand what you want in the second dataset.

Comment: Also, have you made any attempt at this yourself? As it stands, you are simply asking for a community member to do work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Lodash, you can use [`_.uniqWith`](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqWith) to give a custom comparator for finding uniqueness. Mutating the second parameter in the comparator allows you to combine the `id`s.

```js
var obj = {"payload":[{"id":"idval1","type":[{"lists":[{"id":"1234","value":"One","ddid":"dd1","name":"first value"},{"id":"1235","value":"Two","ddid":"dd2","name":"second value"}]}]},{"id":"idval2","type":[{"lists":[{"id":"1234","value":"One","ddid":"dd1","name":"first value"},{"id":"1235","value":"Two","ddid":"dd2","name":"second value"},{"id":"1236","value":"Three","ddid":"dd3","name":"third value"}]}]},{"id":"idval3","type":[{"lists":[{"id":"1234","value":"One","ddid":"dd1","name":"first value"},{"id":"1235","value":"Two","ddid":"dd2","name":"second value"}]}]},{"id":"idval4","type":[{"lists":[{"id":"1234","value":"One","ddid":"dd1","name":"first value"},{"id":"1235","value":"Two","ddid":"dd2","name":"second value"},{"id":"1236","value":"Three","ddid":"dd3","name":"third value"}]}]},{"id":"idval5","type":[{"lists":[{"id":"1234","value":"One","ddid":"dd1","name":"first value"},{"id":"1235","value":"Two","ddid":"dd2","name":"second value"},{"id":"1236","value":"Three","ddid":"dd3","name":"third value"}]}]},{"id":"idval6","type":[{"lists":[{"id":"1234","value":"One","ddid":"dd1","name":"first value"},{"id":"1235","value":"Two","ddid":"dd2","name":"second value"}]}]},{"id":"idval7","type":[{"lists":[{"id":"1234","value":"One","ddid":"dd1","name":"first value"},{"id":"1235","value":"Two","ddid":"dd2","name":"second value"},{"id":"1236","value":"Three","ddid":"dd3","name":"third value"}]}]}]};

obj.payload = _.uniqWith(obj.payload, function(val, accVal) {
  if (_.isEqual(val.type, accVal.type)) {
    accVal.id += "," + val.id;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. Is there any way to check the **"lists"** because we are having some other property in type called **"ddtype": "cs"**  '"type": [{"ddtype": "cs","lists": [{"id": "1234","value": "One","ddid": "dd1","name": "first value"}]}]'. That property having different values so we are not able to use with type. Please advice me on that.

Comment: Can you please edit the input data in the question to show that? I'm not sure I understand. It sounds simple enough, just change what get's compared by `_.isEqual`

Comment: Great! Well in that case it's normal to select the check mark next to the answer so that people know it solved your problem.

Comment: Currently my project using **lodash - 2.4.1** version. I am getting _.uniqWith is not a function. Is there any other function available to achieve this functionality using **lodash - 2.4.1**.

Comment: @Karthikeyan What environment are you working in? You could just [import that single function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.uniqwith), or you could write your own, or you could update lodash.

Comment: i have the following list
**List 1**
"lists": [{
 "id": "1234",
 "value": "One",
 "ddid": "dd1",
 "name": "first value"
},
{
 "id": "1235",
 "value": "Two",
 "ddid": "dd2",
 "name": "second value"
}]
**List 2**
"lists": [{
 "id": "1235",
 "value": "Two",
 "ddid": "dd2",
 "name": "second value"
},
{
 "id": "1234",
 "value": "One",
 "ddid": "dd1",
 "name": "first value"
}]

when I try with uniqWith its returning two array but I need the output as one

Comment: That structure looks very different. If you have more to add to your question, please edit your question. If that is a separate question, create a new question. Make sure to attempt it first though. It will help to look through the [Lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#union)